# ASP.NET MVC3 Chart Web helper doesnt work when hosted on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, helper

I'm using the new chart helper method available in the System.Web.Helpers assembly as shown here

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/(X(1)S(jm1obicbiav03qq3dnxug2ap))/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=597&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

It works just fine when i run the app in visual studio's inbuilt server. But when I publish the website to a virtual directory in IIS on my local machine, the image doesnt show up and in its place a "red cross" mark shows up.

I'm not using any relative paths and static content is available on the server since I can see other images displayed properly in my app when published.

Here's my view

{img src="/Home/GetRainfallChart" alt="chart" /}

This is the action

```
    public ActionResult GetRainfallChart()
    {

        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400).AddSeries(
                               chartType: "area",
                               legend: "Rainfall",
                               xValue: new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" },
                               yValues: new[] { "20", "20", "40", "10", "10" })
                               .Write();
        return null;
    }
```

DO i need to copy any dlls also when publishing?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution

Need to do this for that to work on IIS when hosted on a virtual directory

```
<img src = <%= Url.Content("~/Home/GetRainfallChart") %>" alt="chart" />
```